# Wait for NSNotification before continuing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane-snapshot

I'm sure there is a simple solution but I don't know how to achieve it. I'm writing UI Unit testing for my iOS Application (currently in Objective C but happy for a Swift solution too) so that I can use Fastlane's `snapshot` command but since the application is cloud based simply switching between tabs/views and taking screen shots wouldn't work because the screen shots will only have "Loading..." where as I'd like valid data in them.

My current solution is ugly and unreliable. Currently I'm just waiting 3 seconds via `sleep(3)` and then proceeding. I'm using AFNetworking to perform the requests so I'm just I can just listen to any HTTP request that comes in and if it matches the one I want I can proceed but I'm not sure:

- A: how to capture all inbound traffic
- B: how to halt further execution until I pass an "ok" message.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated because I don't fancy taking hundreds of screen shots manually =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effective UI Tests are written with a different mindset than unit tests and production code. UI Tests should be written from the user's perspective and not care what goes on "under the hood" of the app. For example, your test should wait for a specific UI element to appear instead of waiting for an NSNotification to fire or a specific network request to complete.

#### Wait for An Element to Appear

Let's say your first tab/screen displays user information. Contained in that data is the user's username. You can use XCTest's asynchronous testing API to pause the framework until the element is found (or a timeout occurs).

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let username = self.app.staticTexts["joemasilotti"]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: username, handler: nil)

waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
XCTAssert(username.exists)
```

This comes directly from a [UI Testing cheat sheet](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-wait-for-an-element-to-appear) I put together. It also has a [working example app](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet) that you can run in Xcode and play around with the code and tests.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time when I see developers have this kind of issue it is because of a poorly architected system. However I guess there is never a right answer to how to architect a system. Anyway, instead of creating a linear test case instead create a State Machine test case that uses events. That way you can setup your test. After the setup has completed you tell your thread to go wait on your event queue. The thread/process will wait for events. Then when you get your httpRequest, 10 seconds - or minutes - or however long it takes later, you can pass the test via an event. If there is a timeout in the state machine then you fail the test.

Comment: Good answer. In my defence the project was 3 years old when I picked up on it. I appreciate the answer